# macOSX How to show system message in lldb

Tags: macos, lldb, iokit

I learn to use lldb to debug mac IOKit drivers in macOS 10.12.3.
two machine debug.
It's easy to connect to target machine when panic occurs.
I wonder how to show target machine system message?
Is there any command like "dmesg" in lldb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the target and debugger machine using a FireWire cable. Set the `0x08` bit in the target machine's `debug=` kernel argument (`DB_KPRT`), and anything logged with `kprintf` (note: not `printf`/`IOLog`) will be routed to FireWire. (Firewire is used unless the Mac has a Serial port, which modern Macs do not - virtual machines can, though.)

To view this output, you need to be running the `fwkpfv` command on the Mac on the other end of the Firewire cable.

This method works fine with Thunderbolt-to-Firewire adapters and docks too, although I suspect not if you hotplug them.